# Filtering a model in FIORI leads to "f.forEach is not a function"

Tags: filter, model, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to read a model with a filter:

```
         var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
            filters: [
                new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                    path: 'attr1',
                    operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 
                    value1: value
                }),
                new sap.ui.model.Filter({
                    path: 'attr2', 
                    operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
                    value1: value2
                })
            ], 
            and: true
        });

        model.read("/pathToEntitySet", 
            {
                success: function(oData, response) {
                    console.log("i am here");
                },
                error: function(oError){
                    console.log(oError);
                },
                filters: oFilter
            }
        );
```

However, I am always getting "f.forEach is not a function" when I add filters: oFilter to the model.read operation.

I am using FF 68.5.

Any ideas where this error could be coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filters` expects an array. You passed a single object. Two options:

### Option A: Drop the wrapper

When applying multiple filters with different paths, `AND` is automatically assumed. So you can simply do

```
const aFilter = [
    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: 'attr1',
        operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 
        value1: value
    }),
    new sap.ui.model.Filter({
        path: 'attr2', 
        operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
        value1: value2
    })
];

model.read("/pathToEntitySet", {
    success: ...
    error: ...
    filters: aFilter 
});
```

### Option B: Add another wrapper

Leave your filter as is and just put brackets around `oFilter` when passing it to `filters`:

```
model.read("/pathToEntitySet", {
    success: ...
    error: ...
    filters: [oFilter]
});
```

Comment: Perfect, this is working. But strangely enough, I was using the same filter object (not array) in oTable.bindItems({
      path: 'Model>/pathToEntitySet',
      filters: oFilter})
and here it was working fine.

Comment: Yes. `bindItem` uses a `ListBinding` underneath which automatically converts non-Arrays into arrays. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.ListBinding%23constructor